# download xls/xlsx file from google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

i am trying to download xls or xlsx file but i am getting error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fileNotExportable",
    "message": "Export only supports Docs Editors files."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Export only supports Docs Editors files."
 }
}
```

i am using nodejs. is it possible to download xls xlsx files via api ?

code example:

```js
export function getFileFromStream(auth, fileId, mimeType) {
  const destPath = `/tmp/${fileId}.xls`;
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(destPath);
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    drive.files.export(
      { fileId, mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'},
      { responseType: 'stream'},
      (errrr, response) => {
          response.data
            .on('end', function() {
            console.log('downloaded')
            })
            .on('error', function(err) {
              console.log('Error during download', err);
            })
            .pipe(dest);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) method as used in the [documentation sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_document) can only be used for downloading Google Workspace documents

For downloading non-Google Workspace documents you need to use the [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method as in the [sample for Download a file stored on Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive):

```js
export function getFileFromStream(auth, fileId, mimeType) {
  const destPath = `/tmp/${fileId}.xls`;
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(destPath);
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    drive.files.get({
      fileId: fileId,
      alt: 'media'
    })
      .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
      })
      .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
      })
    .pipe(dest);
}
```